# Force HTTPS for mapped domain pointing to wordpress domain

Tags: htaccess

I have a WordPress install installed and a mapped domain also pointing to the same root.

Example: Installed WordPress is at example-company.com with a mapped domain being example.com.

An SSL is installed on example-company.com which is working fine.

Prior to the installation of SSL example.com mapped to example-company.com (including any subdomains / files linking fine). Now, example.com says that a connection is not secure.

I have tried a rewrite condition to point all traffic to the HTTPS connection on the domain example-company.com but no luck - throws up a too many redirects error.

Is there anyway of doing this with a mapped domain?

Comment: Post your htaccess file snippet here from both companies. Do you have SSH access or just ftp to the server? Also are you running a purchased SSL or one from let's encrypt?

Comment: This is the current code generated from WordPress
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

I tried to add two versions above "Begin Wordpress", one specifying the mapped domain to point to the SSL domain and another requesting all traffic point to the SSL domain. Also using Really Simple SSL plugin